# Where is this admin page loaded from?

Tags: php

I inherited a project with an admin page that is loaded from this url:

```
wp-admin/admin.php?page=dt_intfc5228c10e15432
```

I've searched through the wp-content, wp-admin and wp-includes folders for that page and some content on it.  Could you advise where I should go to edit this page?

The content is a list of payments that have gone through Event Espresso 3 event registration, and I'm looking to modify some of the columns displayed, but I can't find any of the static content (labels, etc) anywhere.

Comment: If it's not in your child or parent theme's functions.php file, it's created by a plugin. You could disable your plugins one-by-one until you determine which plugin is responsible. Once you know which plugin creates the page, you could search for `add_menu_page` to find the function creating it.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality (specifically the code) you are trying to track down will exist in /wp-content/plugins/{EventEspresso3Folder}/ and likely will NOT be named dt_intfc5228c10e15432.

It's going to be a dynamically generated page likely created using add_menu_page() or add_submenu_page() some where in the source code of that plugin.

I haven't used that plugin before so I can't provide exact paths but the method I've described is the WordPress model most plugins follow. If you start searching the plugin code for those helpers it should help you track down the underlying functionality you are looking for.

Comment: I did find it finally.  It is a plug in called DB Toolkit, and the previous developers hid all references to it (slash all menu items) so the clients wouldn't interact with it accidentally.  Took a ton of tracking down...